# Is there any function in confbridge application to mute audio between users?

Tags: asterisk

I needed to make a solution in Asterisk using confbridge application. I made a bridge and assigned admin and users to connect to it. Its working absolutely fine. There is a thing which i am missing and cannot figure out how to get it working. I want to disable communication between users, and enable communication only with admin. Basically I want admin to broadcast audio which all users should be able to hear but when users speak, only admin should be able to hear.
I know there is a way to mute `startmuted` for user but its not working as this option is for muting users for everyone including admin.
My question is: Is it possible for users not to hear each other talking in conference? if yes (most likely) then please guide me how?
Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Confbridge allow mute any channel. It have no users, only channels.

If you need more advanced control like mute only for some groups, you have write your own app or hire developer who do that for you.

Simplest way seams have two conferences and chan_spy, but dialplan logic of such solution is much above average level.